# Why is x undefined when using options object

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, undefined

Why is `x` undefined here? The options object defines them, and then `x` is passed as a parameter to the function foo().

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo() {
  console.log(x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While functions can access values from closures, x is not defined ni the enclosing closure to foo. You however can access it using `options.x` since options is defined in the closure

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo() {
  console.log(options.x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

You can also get the values from the argument passed to the function

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo(value) {
  console.log(value.x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Or you can destructure it from arguments and access it

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo({x}) {
  console.log(x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass options param in foo function...

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo(options) {
  console.log(options.x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Comment: Thanks! When I test your code, it works even if I don't include `options` inside the function `foo();`. Is there a reason that you put `options` inside both the function call `foo(options);` and the function `function foo(options) {}`?

Comment: because of closure you have access to `options` and you access it, but you don't have anything name `x` in closure so you were getting error x is not defined

Comment: in javascript there is a concept call PURE Functions.. try write function with that way. if you write that way you can have more predictable behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no `x` available inside `foo()`. You need have a parameter.You can use [Unpacking fields from objects passed as function parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter).

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo({x,y}) {
  console.log(x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access using the `options` from `closure`

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo() {
  console.log(options.x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

or simply you can accept parameter in function definition and access them.

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo({x,y}) {
  console.log(x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Because**

1. you are not pass `param`  in foo function.so pass param with in function `function foo(param)`
2. And also `x` is not a variable .its object key so call `option.x`
3. Otherwise its still undefined one
4. `option.y` is works.Because you are directly call the object key

```js
var options = {x:4,y:3};

foo(options);
function foo(param) {
  console.log(param.x);
}
console.log(options.y);
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` is undefined because you are not passing it as an argument to your function, and x is not available in parent scopes neither.

You have to declare it in the argument list of your functions. You could also pass the whole object, as the function `bar` shows here. Or you can also pass a full object and destructure in the argument list to get access to its properties, as show by the function `baz` here:

```js
const options = { x: 4, y: 3 };

function foo(x) {
  console.log(x);
}

function bar(arg) {
  console.log(arg.x, arg.y);
}

function baz({ x, y }) {
  console.log(x, y);
}

foo(options.x);
foo(options.y);
bar(options);
baz(options);
```